# ASP.NET - IIS - Tracing

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

I need to trace the **Exceptions** in **IIS 7**.

My application works in **Asp.net** with **c#** in **windows server 2008 R2**. If any **exception** happened in my application,then I need to have a track of that in server.

Please let me know if any features available in **IIS7**.

Comment: In your code you need calls in Try-Catch statements to log the error. The ASP.Net Tracing function is perfect or bubble up the exception to a logging function passing in and logging the Exception.StackTrace.

ASP.NET Tracing Overview

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386420.aspx

Comment: You can also add an Application_Error method in your Global.asax

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use IIS to trace , I think the only possible way is you can use `logging` in IIS .

You can see [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/advanced-logging-module/advanced-logging-for-iis-custom-logging) how to use it !